# Problema com Gradle Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

Estou recebendo um Warning do Gradle para trocar o compile pelo implementation and api, porém não estou mais utilizando o compile no meu projeto.

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
```

Meu Gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.teste.fcmexample"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

O que posso fazer para sanar esse problema? Já dei um clean e um rebuild, mas sem solução. Meu app funciona normal, porém fica esse Warning.

Comment: Estranho, isso daria se ao invés de "implementation" vc estivesse usando o "compile", mas vejo que no seu código está certo

Comment: Fecha o Android Studio, abre dnv e faz o clean

Comment: Não sei mais o que fazer, instalei a nova versão, atualizei o SDK, criei um projeto novo, fiz o procedimento que o @WotonSampaio falou e nada, vou deixar esse Warning ai, rs. Poxa, é chato vê esse alerta sem ter nada errado.

Comment: Cara, se o projeto for novo e vc n tiver feito nada nele, tente criar outro e veja se o erro continua